# What is the best way to write a completion provider for vscode extension for javascript

Tags: javascript, language-server-protocol

What i am doing right now is to identify the current scope of the cursor point and then provide the completions using a hashmap according to the scope.

```
HashMap<String,String[]> program =new HashMap<String, String[]>(){{
            put("function", new String[]{"Function", "function functionName(){\n\t\n}}"});
            put("if", new String[]{"If", "if (true) {\n\t\n}"});
            put("try", new String[]{"Try", "try {\n\t\n}}catch(err) {\nconsole.log(err)}"});
            put("class", new String[]{"Class", "Class className {\n\t\n}}"});
            put("for", new String[]{"For", "for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {\n\t\n}}"});
            put("while", new String[]{"While", "while (true) {\n\t\n}}"});
            put("do", new String[]{"Do", "do {\n\t\n}}while (true);"});
            put("var", new String[]{"Var", "var"});
            put("let", new String[]{"Let", "let"});
            put("const", new String[]{"Const", "const"});
            put("switch", new String[]{"Switch", "switch(expression) {\n" +
                    "            case x:\n" +
                    "                // code block\n" +
                    "                break;\n" +
                    "            case y:\n" +
                    "                // code block\n" +
                    "                break;\n" +
                    "            default:\n" +
                    "                // code block\n" +
                    "        }"});

         }};
        HashMap<String,String[]> sourceElement =new HashMap<String, String[]>(){{
            put("function", new String[]{"Function", "function functionName(){\n\t\n}}"});
            put("if", new String[]{"If", "if (true) {\n\t\n}"});
            put("try", new String[]{"Try", "try {\n\t\n}}catch(err) {\nconsole.log(err)}"});
```

and then use swith to select the correct hashmap.

```
JsonObject mainObj = new JsonObject();
        switch(finalScope) {
            case "program":
                mainObj.add("re",generateArray(program));
                break;
            case "sourceelement":
                mainObj.add("re",generateArray(sourceElement));
```

like wise. what i want to know is is there a good way than thisto do tha task. I am using antlr4 to parse the code. and write my lsp using the java

Comment: `HashMap<String,String[]>` does not really look like JavaScript to me.

Comment: @MauriceNino I am writing my code from java. What I need to write a code to give completions (basically like in vscode) for javascript